# NGINX restarts fails every time after adding a second virtual host

Tags: nginx, server, debian, vhosts

I dont know what i am doing wrong.
First I tried to add Vhosts in NGINX making new file in sites-available then linken to sites-enabled. This doerst work.

Then I tried to make the vhosts directly in the nginx.conf file. There is the same Problem. It works perfectly for one host but then if I add a another one and try to  `/etc/init.d/nginx` start it always says:

```
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

How can I fix that?
Here ist my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name_;
        location / {
            root /var/www/html/;
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            autoindex on;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /var/www/html/;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.de;
        location / {
            root /var/www/dev1/;
            index index.html index.htm;
            autoindex on;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /var/www/dev1/;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at the error log, and/or test the Nginx configuration using `nginx -t`.

Comment: [so] is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.